# How de-increment image order when an image is deleted in individual blog posts. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to de-increment the images order column if an image has been deleted in a particular blog post, the images are de-incrementing but it's not getting the post id. Basically the images order for every blog post should begin with 1 however it seems to be incrementing the order numbers from previous blog posts. I tried passing in the post id but run into a few issues, appreciate the help thank you.

```
public function destroy(Images $image)
    {
        $image->delete();

        $image->update(['order' => 0]);

        $images = Images::all();
        $post = Post::all();

        $i = 1;

        foreach ($images as $img){
            $img->timestamps = false;
            $id = $img->id;

            $img->update(['order' => $i])->where('post_id', $post->id);
            $i++;
        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('message','Image Deleted!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after `$image->update(['order' => 0]);` use

```
DB::statement('UPDATE images SET order = order - 1 WHERE id > '.$image->id);
```

it will only update the necessary records, not the entire table.
And you will get rid of foreach

and remove

```
    $images = Images::all();
    $post = Post::all();

    $i = 1;

    foreach ($images as $img){
        $img->timestamps = false;
        $id = $img->id;

        $img->update(['order' => $i])->where('post_id', $post->id);
        $i++;
    }
```

---

As a second option, you can do so here

```
public function destroy(Images $image)
{
    $image->delete();

    $image->update(['order' => 0]);

    $images = Images:where('post_id', $image->post_id)->orderBy('post_id')->get();
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($images as $img){
        $img->timestamps = false;

        $img->update(['order' => $i]);
        $i++;
    }

    return Redirect::back()->with('message','Image Deleted!');
}
```

Comment: I seem to get an sql syntax error from that query, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order - 1

Comment: @BrandonK I changed the comment. Check please

Comment: Just tried the new query still getting the same syntax error.

Comment: @BrandonK Can you tell me which version of MySQL you have?

Comment: I'm using version 5.7.26

Comment: @BrandonK You need a minimum version of 5.7.30.
Is there an opportunity for version updates?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of MAMP and it comes will MySQL 5.7.26 so I don't think I can update it.

Comment: @BrandonK There is version 5.7.30 https://documentation-4.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/How-Tos/MySQL/InstallMySQL57/

Comment: @BrandonK I added a new method for you

Comment: Thanks just tested this and it is working really well.

Comment: @BrandonK I was glad to help :) But on many servers there is a version of MySQL 5.7.30+. If possible, update the version, since the first option works much faster with less code

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to update the order of images in a certain post you will need:

1. `hasMany` relationship in *Post* Model:

   ```
    public function images()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(Images::class);
   }
   ```
2. Reconstruct the `delete` function:

   ```
   public function destroy(Images $image)
   {
      $postId = $image->post_id;

      $image->delete();

      $images = Post::find($postId)->images;

      $i = 1;

      foreach ($images as $img){
          $img->timestamps = false;

           $img->update(['order' => $i]);

         $i++;
      }

      return Redirect::back()->with('message','Image Deleted!');
   }
   ```

Comment: I have belongTo relationship defined in my model that points to the post model, when I added your change I get Call to a member function where() on bool.

Comment: @BrandonK Try it now

Comment: When I delete the selected image it resets the order for the rest of images in that post to 22 and 24 for example, as it is incrementing the order number from the first post I think.

Comment: so you want to chane the `order` for all post images or just the post images of the deleted image?

Comment: Yes so each post can have multiple images and the order should always start with 1. So if there were 3 images 1,2,3 and image 2 was deleted in that post then the new order should be 1,2 but it shouldn't change the other images order in other posts which is what is happening now, if that makes sense.

Comment: @BrandonK ok Try it now.